# How can i write code about different colors, different radius balls in java

Tags: java, arrays

**Main class** this is main class of my program

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BallWorld frm = new BallWorld(3);
        frm.setVisible(true);           


        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            frm.stepTheBall();
        }
    }
}
```

**BallWorld.java class** this class related with JFrame

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class BallWorld extends JFrame {
    public final int FRAMEWIDTH = 600;
    public final int FRAMEHEIGHT = 400;

    private Ball[] ballArr;
    private int ballCnt;

    public BallWorld(int ballCnt){
        super();
        setSize(FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);
        setTitle("My Bouncing Ball Application");

        ballArr = new Ball[ballCnt];
        this.ballCnt = ballCnt;

        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){
            ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,50), 5);
            int ddx = (int) (5*Math.random()); //Exercise 1
            int ddy = (int) (4*Math.random());  //Exercise 1
            ballArr[i].setMotion(ddx, ddy); 
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){
            ballArr[i].paint(g);    
        }
    }

    public void stepTheBall(){
        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){        
            ballArr[i].move();

            Point loc = ballArr[i].getLocation();

            if (loc.x < ballArr[i].getRadius() ||
                loc.x > FRAMEWIDTH-ballArr[i].getRadius()){
                ballArr[i].reclectVert();
            }

            if (loc.y < ballArr[i].getRadius() ||
                    loc.y > FRAMEHEIGHT-ballArr[i].getRadius()){
                ballArr[i].reclectHoriz();
            }
        }   
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Ball.java class** this class related with balls information

```
public class Ball {

        private Point location;
        private int radius;
        private Color color;
        private int dx, dy;

        public Ball(Point l, int r, Color c){
            location = l;
            radius = r;
            color = c;
        }

        public Ball(Point l, int r){
            location = l;
            radius = r;
            color = Color.RED;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public void setRadius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void setMotion(int dx, int dy){
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        public void move(){
            location.translate(dx, dy);
        }

        public void moveTo(int x, int y){
            location.move(x, y);
        }

        public void paint (Graphics g) {
            g.setColor (color);
            g.fillOval (location.x-radius, location.y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
        }

        public void reclectHoriz() {
            dy = -dy;       
        }   

        public void reclectVert() {
            dx = -dx;       
        }
    }
```

I want to add yellow,blue,red balls and different radius that includes. How can i write that informations

Comment: Could you maybe rephrase your question? I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: Not really how this site works. Can you be more specific - preferably with MUCH less code for people to trawl through? What exactly is the problem - the code so far suggests you have a basic grasp so what is missing for you? Instantiation of an object?

Comment: when you run that codes, it will shows 3 red balls.I need to add different color balls, but i dont know how to add.Also that balls has a different radius or size

Comment: yes, i want to new ball object.

Comment: @anilleuss Please edit your question to include the actual question, rather than burying it in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the lines at fault:

`ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,50), 5);`

Here, you call the two-argument constructor from Ball. It looks like this:

```
public Ball(Point l, int r){
        location = l;
        radius = r;
        color = Color.RED;
    }
```

So your balls will all be red, have a radius of 5 and be at position 50,50. You do have a three-argument constructor that also sets the color of a ball. If you want these things to be random, use a `Random` object, select a random color, radius and point for each ball, and there you go.

It should be clear how you get random numbers for radius and point. In case you're wondering about Color, here's a way: Define an array containing Color objects.

`Color[] colors = {Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow};`

Get a random number based on the size of the array,

`int colornumber = random.nextInt(colors.length);`

and retrieve the color

`Color c = colors[colornumber]`

Then, create balls with random properties.

---

EDIT

```
public class BallWorld {
....
private Random random = new Random();
private Color[] colors={Color.red,Color.blue,Color.yellow};

public BallWorld(int ballCnt){
    super();
    setSize(FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);
    setTitle("My Bouncing Ball Application");

    ballArr = new Ball[ballCnt];
    this.ballCnt = ballCnt;

    for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){
---->   // Create attributes here
        int bcn = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        Color ballcolor = colors[bcn];
        int ballradius = random.nextInt(10); // change to suit your needs
---->   int posx = random.nextInt(200); // change to suit your needs
---->   int posy = random.nextInt(200); // change to suit your needs
        // this creates a ball given the above calculated parameters
---->   ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(posx,posy), ballradius, ballcolor);
        int ddx = (int) (5*Math.random()); //Exercise 1
        int ddy = (int) (4*Math.random());  //Exercise 1
        ballArr[i].setMotion(ddx, ddy); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created a Random object? `Random random = new Random();`

Comment: Yes, i created.
public class Ball {
 
 Random random = new Random();
 
 private Point location;
 private int radius;
 private Color[] colors={Color.red,Color.blue,Color.yellow};
 private int colorNumber=random.nextInt(colors.length);
 Color c = colors[colorNumber];  but it gives error at g.setColor                                                     public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(colors);

Comment: You cannot pass `colors` to `setColor`, because `colors` is an *array of Color*, not a *Color*

Comment: what can i write for that part?

Comment: Great!!, can you help me 2 more questions?

Comment: Sure, but I'd prefer to continue the discussion somewhere else, not as comments here...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,50), 5);
```

use another constructor:

```
ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,50), 5, Color.xxx);
```

Comment: if i wrtie this ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,30),6,Color.yellow); i have 3 yellow balls, but i dont want to same color balls. it should be different colors.

Comment: `ballArr[0]=...; ballArr[1]=...; ballArr[2]=...;`